# assign @changeset not available in eex template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to learn the Phoenix's Form system with including the Ecto.Model's but i have encountered a problem that i can't pass. I have created a form:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <%= form_for @changeset, user_path(@conn, :create), fn f -> %>
    <label>
      Login: <%= text_input f, :login %>
    </label>
    <label>
      Password: <%= password_input f, :password %>
    </label>
    <label>
      Name: <%= text_input f, :name %>
    </label>
    <label>
      Surname: <%= text_input f, :name %>
    </label>
    <label>
      Email: <%= email_input f, :name %>
    </label>
    <label>
      Class: <%= text_input f, :name %>
    </label>
    <label>
      Phone: <%= text_input f, :name %>
    </label>

    <%= submit "Submit" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

That is being served by Controller:

```
  def index(conn, _params) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{})
    render conn, "index.html", changeset: changeset
  end

  def create(conn, _params) do
    IO.inspect(_params)
    render conn, "index.html"
  end
```

And the model:

```
defmodule Kpsz.Model.User do
  use Kpsz.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :login, :string
    field :password, :string
    field :email, :string

    field :role, :integer

    field :name, :string
    field :surname, :string
    field :class, :string
    field :phone_number, :string

    has_many :presences, Kpsz.Model.Presence
  end

  @required_fields ~w(login,password,email,name,surname,class,phone_number)
  @optional_fields ~w(role)

  def changeset(user, params \\ :empty) do
    case params do
      :empty -> cast(user,params, ~w(),~w())
      _ -> user
        |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
        |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
        |> unique_constraint(:email)
    end
  end

end
```

I have pattern matched the params, because i was getting bunch of errors while creating empty changeset for passing it to the form. Is there any better way around it?

And error I am getting after submiting the form:
[image]

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong and give some info how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are rendering the same view and template from both actions.

This line:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, user_path(@conn, :create), fn f -> %>
```

References `@changeset` which is expected to be passed to your Eex template via assigns. In a phoenix controller you do this by calling:

```
render(conn, template, assigns)
```

In your case you are passing the changeset on `index` but not on `create`. Normally your form will be rendered in the `new` function and the params will be used in the changeset function in the `create` function.

Consider generating this code to see how it works:

```
mix phoenix.gen.html User name surname email age:integer
```

Comment: "** (Mix) The task ecto.gen.html could not be found"

Comment: @Haito Sorry - that should have been `mix phoenix.gen.html`

Comment: what type should i write for datetime? (i mean i havo to do date: what)

Comment: `:datetime` should work https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.0.4/lib/mix/tasks/phoenix.gen.model.ex#L202 e.g. `age:integer some_time:datetime`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but with a partial...I was passing my changeset through my `page#index` like

```
 def index(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "index.html", %{
      :other_stuff => true,
      :changeset =>  %Ecto.Changeset{}
    })
 end
```

Inside of my `index.html.eex` I had the partial rendering like:

```
<%= render("_dialog.html", conn: @conn) %>
```

The changeset needed to be passed into the partial the same as conn is, like:

```
<%= render("_dialog.html", conn: @conn, changeset: @changeset) %>
```