# After moving code from index.html.eex to app.html.eex: assign @user not available in eex template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I moved some code to app.html.eex from post/index.html.eex

```
  <%= if @user do %>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>Hello <%= @user.username %>!</li>
          </ul>
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li> <%= link "logout", to: session_path(@conn, :logout), method: :delete, class: "logout-button" %></li>
      </ul>
      </ul>
        <% else %>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li ><a class="login" href="/users/signin">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a class="signup" href="/users/new">Signup</a></li>
      </ul>
      <% end %>
```

When a user tries to log on, it raises:

```
assign @user not available in eex template.
Please make sure all proper assigns have been set. If this
is a child template, ensure assigns are given explicitly by
the parent template as they are not automatically forwarded.
Available assigns: [:conn, :view_module, :view_template]
```

Here is part of the code from user controller:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
    users = Auths.list_users()
    render(conn, "index.html", users: users)
  end

  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Auths.change_user(%Citybuilder.Auths.User{})
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    case Auths.create_user(user_params) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Welcome! Happy writing :)")
        |> redirect(to: "/users/signin")
      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end

  def signin(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "signin.html")
  end
```

**I'm unsure how to specifically reference app.html.eex from the controller.**

I looked at similar questions but could not find an answer:

[assign @changeset not available in eex template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982990/assign-changeset-not-available-in-eex-template)

I need to add assigns after "signin.html.eex", following the `conn, template, assigns` pattern.

```
def signin(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "signin.html")
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

By `<%= if @user %>`, I'm assuming you want to test if this variable is assigned by the controller or not. In that case, you can't use the `@` syntax as it raises an error if the variable is not set. You can instead use the `assigns` map (the map that contains all the bindings) with bracket access syntax.

Change:

```
<%= if @user do %>
```

To:

```
<%= if user = assigns[:user] do %>
```

And then, in the code inside the `if`, change all `@user` to just `user`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. To clarify; The code block checks if the user is logged on. If they are, it prints a welcome message, and logout button in the navbar. If there is no logon, it offers only login and signup.